# Java - Jackcess API with .accde(MS Access) format

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

is it possible to read .accde format file from jackcess API?if yes, sample code or syntax please.

The below code works with .accdb format.

```
public Database getDatabase() {
Database db;
    try {
        String accessFileName = "C:\\folder\\file.accdb";
        db = Database.open(new File(accessFileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return db;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just gave a try using the same(above) code by changing from accdb to accde format, its working.

```
public Database getDatabase() {
Database db;
try {
    String accessFileName = "C:\\folder\\file.accde";
    db = Database.open(new File(accessFileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return db;
}
```